# Change the local source to database source

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

How can I change the source (in line 13) from local to my database?

I want to have the suggestions retrieve from the database.

I too hope that the suggestions style will be similar to typeahead.js.

This is my current code:

```
<html>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//raw.github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css/master/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.q.typeahead').typeahead({                               
                name: "q",                
                local: ['italy', 'france', 'england', 'united states', 'brazil', 'spain']                                              
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //document.getElementById("suggestion")

            function getSuggestion(q) {

            var ajax;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)//for ie7+, FF, Chrome
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();//ajax object
            else
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//for ie6 and previous
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(ajax.status === 200 && ajax.readyState === 4) {
                    //if result are not there then don't display them
                    if(ajax.responseText === "")
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    }
                }
            };
            ajax.open("GET", "suggestion.php?q=" + q, false);
            ajax.send();
        }
    </script>

    <input type="text" class="q typeahead" id="citiesInput" />

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to write some server side code to access your database. You could load the data via ajax or perhaps as script directly into javascript, but really you need to understand client/server technologies.

Comment: This is my new code, can you check for me? [Code](http://pastebin.com/2hN6zGN7)

Comment: You have jQuery loaded, use it's provided Ajax function.   Don't do your own XMLHttpRequest code.

Comment: @SteveWellens What do you mean? Can you guide me?

Comment: @user3144149 jQuery has an Ajax function that 'normalizes' the differences between browsers so you don't have to deal with them.  Have you Googled jQuery Ajax yet?

Comment: @SteveWellens Yes I have, could you please help me with the whole code?

Comment: @user3144149 - Not unless you are willing to give me a PO number and I can reference it when I send you invoices.   Besides, and more importantly, you need to be able to dig this stuff out on your own.  When you get stuck on a specific problem, people here will help you.